# eBPF program appears to duplicate packets sometimes

Tags: linux-networking, udp

I am trying to understand behaviour of eBPF/XDP under Linux. I have 2 machines connected by an isolated 100gE network. On one I run a udp sender application which is configured to send 10M packets of 1 byte each. On the other I run an eBPF/XDP application which receives the packets and reports counts. Sometimes when I run the test case, I see 10M packets at the receiver; exactly the same number as were sent. Other times, I see just under 20M packets at the receiver.
Can anyone tell me what is causing the 20M packet behaviour ?

Comment: Can you share your eBPF code?

Comment: My code is here https://github.com/tjcw/xdp-tutorial/tree/master/udp-sender

Comment: The sender application runs with "./udp-sender 10.1.0.2 8000" where 10.1.0.2 is the IP address of the receiver, and 8000 is the number of an unoccupied UDP port (nothing receives the packets on the receiver, and when running the af_xdp_user XDP program drops the UDP packets)